# MobilePush Sendlog

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, logging

i am using the MobilePush Sendlog template however i want to add additional data to the sendlog much like i have done with the email sendlog.

Specifically i want to trap the Message type (location, outbound etc), location that triggred the message, messagename and the message content.

All of this data is available within the reports so it must be available somewhere i just cant determine the fieldnames to create in the DE nor the Ampscript to use to get these values.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

I have spoken to support but no luck there either
Thanks